# Example of inductive sets that are neither least nor greatest fixed point

Tags: logic, inductive-datatypes

Do there exist a set of inductive rules and a fixed point of these rules but is neither the least nor the greatest fixed points?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's a non-trivial example:

Suppose we want to define inductively a subset of reals, so we work on the complete lattice $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R})$ ordered by inclusion.

Then, consider the rules
$$
\dfrac{\qquad}{0} \qquad \dfrac{x}{x+1}
$$
This induces the (monotonic, Scott-continuous) function $f : \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R}) \to \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R})$ given by
$$
f(X) = \{0\} \cup \{ x+1 \ |\ x\in X\}
$$

All of the following are fixed points of $f$:

- $\mathbb{N}$ (least)
- $\mathbb{Z}$
- $\{x/2 \ |\ x\in \mathbb{Z}\}$
- $\{x/3 \ |\ x\in \mathbb{Z}\}$
- etc.
- for any natural $k \geq 1$, the set $\{x/k \ |\ x\in \mathbb{Z} \}$
- $\mathbb{Q}$
- $\mathbb{R}$ (greatest)

If we want our definition to be well-formed, beyond specifying the rules, we need to single out one the fixed points. This is typically done by taking the least (induction) or the greatest (coinduction).

Comment: A minor nit, but without specifying least/greatest or some other property to uniquely pick out the appropriate subset, this doesn't inductively *define* a subset of the reals.

Comment: @DerekElkins Agreed. I added a note about that.

Comment: @DerekElkins The answer doesn't claim that it defines anything. It says to suppose that we _want_ to define something, gives some rules and says that those rules have a whole bunch of fixed points.

Comment: @DavidRicherby Indeed, that was my intention. Still, I can see that it is possible to read a bit beyond what I wrote, so I added a final note anyway.

Comment: Thank you. My professor used the same rules but his definition of greatest fixed point is somehow different. His greatest set is the natural numbers with an additional infinite element whose successor is itself. He seems to assume the property that 0 has no predecessor for these types of sets.

Comment: @thbl2012 The greatest fixed point is very sensitive to the choice of the complete lattice you work on. Here, I started with $\mathbb{R}$ as the top element of my lattice, but I could have chosen e.g. $\mathbb{Q}$ or $\mathbb{C}$. Another common choice it the set of finite or infinite symbolic applications of the ocnstructors, where, as you say, you do have the largest fixed point being $\mathbb{N} \cup \{\infty\}$ where $\infty$ here represents the successor applied on itself infinitely many times. Hence, your professor is completely correct, (s)he simply chose another complete lattice.

Answer (score 6):

Any set is a fixed point of the empty set of rules or of the trivial rule $x\in X\Rightarrow x\in X$.